# Instantiating generic class in java?

Tags: java, java-ee-7

I am using Java1.7 and using generics.

I wrote a generic class as below.

```
 public class SomeCollection<T extends MyPojo<K>, K> {



    }
```

Now, how can i instantiate above class? I mean how can i create an instance for above class?

I am doing as: `SomeCollection<MyPojoSubClass, SomeType> sss = new SomeCollection<>();` Compiler  is not giving any error. IS it correct way ?

Thanks!

Comment: `SomeCollection<MyPojo<String>,String>> collection = new SomeCollection<>();` assuming you have not made the default constructor private and you use a string as a "key" (K) - however - keys are usually used as the first generic type and should consist of an immutable class - else you won't be able to retrieve the value which belongs to the key.

Comment: Replace T and K with your desired class. And create the object as usual you create in java

Comment: I am doing as: SomeCollection<MyPojoSubClass, SomeType> sss = new SomeCollection<>(); Compiler  is not giving any error. IS it correct way ?

Comment: only if MyPojoSubClass is defined like `class MyPojoSubClass extends MyPojo<SomeType>`

Comment: Yes..correct..Thanks much...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new SomeCollection<MyPojo<String>, String>();
```

Or are we missing something?

Comment: @user755806 yup it is correct. that is called the diamond operator and it is specific for java 7, it was made so that we do not type that much.